# AWS Upload with multipart/form-data Invalid

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, form-data

I am sending a file to the presignedPOST url to upload to AWS S3 and in other resources I've found, to send a file with `form-data` is to switch to `multipart/form-data` to send a file.

This is the form data I've created is this:

```
fields['file'] = new File([this.get_compressed_photo],manifest.photo, {type: "image/jpeg"});
var form = new FormData();

for(let field in fields){
    form.append(field+"", fields[field]);
}

try {
    response = await axios.post(my_url, form, {
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data",
        }
    }); 
}catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
```

this is the field in the form in the PARAMs for the request:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file_name.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

function() {
    [native code]
}
```

Is something going wrong here?

UPDATE:
AWS does respond, but not with an error that is relevant to the file. I'm not sure if this means that the file is still valid, but just looking at the value for the image file, I'm not sure how.

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>....
```

I'm using the `aws-sdk` and creating the presignedPOST url like so:

```
....
    let path = process.env.PATH + identifier + "/" + file_name;
    var url = false;

    try{
        const url = await s3.createPresignedPost({
            Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
            Expires: (60 * 5),
            Fields : {
                key: path,
                AWSAccessKeyId: process.env.KEY,
            },
        });
        return url;
    }catch(error){
        return false;
    }
....
```

Do I still need to add a signature to this?

Comment: **All** of the form fields must be passed to `Fields : { ... }`

Comment: Can you be more specific with your comment please? I appreciate your help

Comment: Actually, the issue here isn't really what I originally suspected.  Have you reviewed the low-level docs on how to perform a pre-signed `POST` upload?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html shows significantly more form fields than what's in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the unneeded `AWSAccessKeyId` in the fields object. In an example somewhere I saw that it was added so I added it initially.

Removing it makes it works like a charm and I think it messes up AWS's specific required order of the fields.

```
....
    let path = process.env.PATH + identifier + "/" + file_name;
    var url = false;

    try{
        const url = await s3.createPresignedPost({
            Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
            Expires: (60 * 5),
            Fields : {
                key: path,          // key is the only required field here
                //AWSAccessKeyId: process.env.KEY, << I COMMENTED OUT THIS LINE
            },
        });
        return url;
    }catch(error){
        return false;
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wasted a day trying to get multipart POSTs to S3 working with AWS signature v4.

The POST kept failing with a 403 Forbidden response with SignatureDoesNotMatch. I was 100% certain my signature was correct as I was using the AWS SDK to generate it, and I knew my keys were correct.

I had my POST field name for the signature as 'Signature' rather than 'x-amz-signature' as per the docs, because changing it to 'x-amz-signature' just resulted in a 400 response instead of the 403, with an error message saying I was missing the Signature field!

It then dawned on me that S3 was trying to verify my request as if it was signed using AWS signature version 2! The fix was to use 'x-amz-signature' as per the docs, but also to make sure the 'x-amz-algorithm' field in the multipart POST data was before all others! The AWS docs do not show it like this. Clearly S3 requires this field to come first so it knows what algorithm to use.

I ended up with the following order that now works:
x-amz-algorithm
x-amz-credential
policy
x-amz-date
x-amz-signature
...